# MySQL Create trigger for get value from another column

Tags: mysql, triggers

i have a table which contains columns as "barkoda1,barkoda2,barkoda3,@pdfa1,@pdfa2,@pdfa3", what i'm trying to do is when a record assigned to barkoda1 copy same record to @pdfa1,for example if barkoda1 defined as "1234567890" @pdfa1 should be "1234567890.pdf".

i tried to create a trigger for it, but failed;

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER pdfdeneme AFTER INSERT
ON finyeb_ba_2369_bio_for_2__r_d_
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE finyeb_ba_2369_bio_for_2__r_d_ SET `@pdfa1`=NEW.barkoda1;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

when i create this trigger,it doesn't return any error but when i add record to table mysql returns "it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger".

also tried this way

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER pdfdeneme BEFORE INSERT
ON finyeb_ba_2369_bio_for_2__r_d_
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO finyeb_ba_2369_bio_for_2__r_d_(`@pdfa1`) VALUES(NEW.barkoda1);
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

But same error happened, what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: You only need the set part of the statement..with a concat for the .pdf part

Comment: @P.Salmon oh you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER

And then only use the SET Clause

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER pdfdeneme BEFORE INSERT
ON finyeb_ba_2369_bio_for_2__r_d_
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET NEW.`@pdfa1` =  CONCAT(NEW.barkoda1,'.pdf');
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

But your column name is a bad choice, it leads on the first glance to false conclusions.

Comment: you are right about column name,unfortunately it's not my design,i need to continue over it and that column names causing problem all the time, thanks for your help.